# Wordpress public api, find posts by parent id

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

I'm moving a site from a custom CMS to WordPress.com for the back end. The public REST api is working well so far, but I can't filter pages by parent id. Here's the working endpoint that fetches a list of the pages:

[public posts endpoint](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/comerbebermx.wordpress.com/posts?type=page)

You can note that the parent of the first item is properly set:

```
 "parent": { "ID": 341, "type": "page"... }
```

But filtering the posts resource by parent_id ([post api docs](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/get/sites/%24site/posts/)) returns an empty data set.

[posts filtered by parent_id](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/comerbebermx.wordpress.com/posts?parent_id=341)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. You need to specify the 'type' parameter since it defaults to post.

[link with type specified](https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/comerbebermx.wordpress.com/posts/?parent_id=341&type=page)